# pointer array doesn't gets printed

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    int i;
    int *as[2];
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        *as[i]=i;
        printf("%d\n",*as[i]);
    }
}
```

This is my code. I am expecting to print values 1
2

But when I run the code the console prints nothing. What have I done wrong?

Comment: where is as's allocated area?

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: You should probably have gotten a warning about this from the compiler... except that you don't. So, I've filed [this one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102996) against GCC and [this one](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52343) against clang. Which compiler were you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` character in C language is not a simple decoration. It declares a pointer that has to point to *something*. Here you declared an array of two pointers, but never initialized the pointer themselves. And dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is explicitely Undefined Behaviour (the hell for C programmers). If you want to process integers, get rid of the pointers:

```
int as[2];
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    as[i]=i;
    printf("%d\n",as[i]);
}
```

Or if you really want to process pointers, ensure that they are initialized to point to a valid object:

```
int *as[2];
int data[2]
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    as[i] = &(data[i]);   // Ok, as[i] now points to a valid integer
    *as[i]=i;
    printf("%d\n",*as[i]);
}
```

BTW, the idiomatic way to get the address of an element of an array would be:

```
    as[i] = data + i;
```

Comment: i want to use pointer in my program, but could you help me to initialize a pointer array using allocation rather than using & of another variable

Comment: @KishoreKumarS Look for the `malloc` function in your C programming book.

Comment: Apparently, though OP is not getting a warning about this from GCC.

Comment: int *as;
as=malloc(2*sizeof(int));
IT WORKS